# Find values of $p>0$ so that the integral converges.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> > $$\int_0^1 \frac{x-\ln(1+x)}{x^p}\,dx$$
>
> Find the values of $p > 0$ so that the integral converges.

I don't have any idea.

How to think about it?

The answer is $0<p<3$

Comment: The integral is improper because of $x=0$. In order for this integral to exist, the limit $x→0$ (from the RHS) needs to exist. I can see some L'Hospital here. This is just a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the comparison test and
$$
\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3).
$$
As $x\to0$,
$$
\frac{x-\ln(1+x)}{x^p}=x^{2-p}+O(x^{3-p}).
$$
The integral behaves like$$
\int_0^1x^{2-p}\,dx,
$$
which is convergent if $2-p>-1$.

Comment: Well...I still don't get it.Could you show me more details?

Comment: I have included details.

Comment: Oh,no wonder I didn't get it because I haven't learned Taylor series.But still thank you very much!:)

Comment: You do not need Taylor series. You can find the same result using L'Hôpital's rule:$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}=-\frac12.$$ Knowing about the Taylor expansion is useful because it gives you the right exponent: $2$.

Comment: Ok,I think I know how to solve the similar type questions.Thx again!